# Return a list of the sum of n integers in a list

Tags: python, list, loops, python-2.7, sum

I'm trying to write a function that will return a list that is made up of the sum of n integers in  a list. I know that sounds confusing.

For example :

```
List = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]

n = 5
```

the function should return `[15,40,65]`

I have a for loop created right now but it keeps using a preceding term that I don't want it to so the sum is always incorrect.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: can you post your code?

Answer (score 6):

Use a list comprehension and slicing:

```
>>> lis = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
>>> n = 5
>>> [sum(lis[i:i+n]) for i in xrange(0, len(lis), n)]
[15, 40, 65]
```